# Jquery - Supersized image resize on Android Browser

Tags: android, iphone, webkit, browser, desktop

I m trying to use http://buildinternet.com/2011/07/supersized-3-2-fullscreen-jquery-slideshow/
on a web page, which works fine across desktop and iOS browsers, sadly the images stretch in android devices (I suppose), I've only tried it on Samsung S3.

Page in questions: quanttus.com

Help?